# What happens when ultrasound hits metal?

Tags: electromagnetism, acoustics, radiation

What happens when ultrasound hits metal? Would it generate heat? Would it alter the EMF readings the metal would normally emit? How would it affect normal radiation levels? Would sine, saw and square waves produce different results?

Comment: How does metal "normally emit EMF readings"?  I tried Googling it, and all I got was a bunch of pseudoscience sites like mercola.com.

Answer (score 1):

> What happens when ultrasound hits metal?

When a sound wave, ultrasound or otherwise, reaches a metal surface, the pressure from the wave causes the metal to vibrate, creating a corresponding sound wave in the metal itself.  Some of the energy gets transmitted in this way, the rest gets reflected off the surface.

> Would it generate heat?

Depends on the setup.  Generally speaking, metals behave pretty elastically when subjected to ultrasound, which means they conserve energy, converting very little of it into heat.  However, other materials will rapidly turn the kinetic energy of the sound wave into heat.

> Would it alter the EMF readings the metal would normally emit?

Metals do not emit EMF.  You need something like a battery to cause EMF, and it generally will not have a meaningful effect on EMF.

> How would it affect normal radiation levels?

Radiation is completely and utterly unrelated to ultrasound in every way.  There would be utterly no effect on radiation levels.  Zero.

> Would sine, saw and square waves produce different results?

They would produce sine saw and square waves, so yes, there would be a difference.  However, the difference would not be anything other than the intuitive effects of the different waves.  It would be worth noting that the mass of the metal may have a low-pass effect, making it easier to pass low frequencies.  If so, you would expect to see some distortion of the saw and square waves.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to understand what is happening with a piece of metal shelving in our place. It generates an emf of about 250-300 micro Tesla. It's not touching any wires and is not conducting electricity. Nearby radiation levels are elevated at 18-34 cpm. It does feel "prickly" when you put your hand on it. It vibrates at 27 hz and 1750 rpms. There is nothing mechanical near it. If I put my foot near it for any length of time, my foot begins to feel very hot. Since I can't find any electric or magnetic reasons for it, I began to wonder about sound-based solutions. Any ideas?

Comment: @Jason I don't think it's something that can be figured out over the internet, because it's hard to tell what is happening without getting to see it.  However, I would strongly question whether it is *actually* electrically isolated.  Is this shelving screwed into the wall?  If it isn't, try moving it.  If it is screwed into the wall, there's a chance that it's screwed into the power lines in the wall!  Obviously, without being there, I can't say anything for sure, but at least some of the issues you mention (EMF, "prickly" roughly 30Hz vibration) are consistent with what I have seen

Comment: for a piece of metal that's in contact with the hot side of a power line.  This theory could be tested with a voltmeter measuring the AC voltage between ground in a nearby wall socket and the metal.  If it reads 120V, it's a great time to hit the breaker, confirm that the voltage of the shelf goes back down to 0V, and remove the shelving before you get hurt!

Comment: The shelving isn't screwed into the wall. If I remove it, the field(s) are still there, but nowhere near as pronounced. It appears to be coming from our neighbour's place next door (we are in a condo), but he assures me that he has nothing in that location that would generate any type of field.

Comment: Here's one thing I didn't mention - using a gaussmeter that measures magnetic field only, sometimes (but not all the time), the field rhythmically pulsates anywhere between 1-3 milligauss to 15-30 milligauss. While the shelving doesn't register as conducting electricity, occasionally the nearby wall registers as conducting electricity at anywhere from 3-70 milligaus, but higher up at about chest level where there is no wiring in the walls. None of these events are necessarily concurrent. No one has any idea what's causing any of this. But it's made that particular location unusable.

Comment: As a serious solution, have you considered calling some decent ghost hunters?  Any ghost hunter worth their salt should be quite good at identifying false alarms, and the causes behind their false alarms are *exactly* the kind of cause you are looking for, so they may actually be a perfect consultant!

Comment: Are you serious? I used to have a roommate who watched those ghost hunting shows and they always used to check out the electrical panel first (I just used to laugh). But it's not something I would have considered to explore what is causing a localized event. Are you saying that they would have the tools and expertise to get to the bottom of what is physically happening?

Comment: I would say a good ghost hunter would.  Mind you it may not be easy to tell a good ghost hunter from a total hack, but anyone who is truly serious about trying to scientifically study ghosts is going to need to have the skills needed to rule out the large number of false-positives they deal with in that business, and they work with those sorts of devices all the time.  Of course, the worst case scenario *is* that they tell you your house is haunted, but that's a risk you might have to take!